# How to filter data, using checkboxes, without using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React to display book titles that I want filtered by category. I want the titles filtered once a checkbox next to the category name is clicked. I am not using a submit button.

I am somewhat new to React and read the documentation about "lifting state," but I haven't been able to get that to work. I have not yet read the Hooks or Context API documentation. Perhaps that's the solution, but it seems what I'm doing isn't complex enough for that...maybe not?

```
class Checkbox extends Component {
    state = {
        checked: false
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState(() => ({ checked: !this.state.checked }))
    }

    render() {
        const name = this.props.name;
        return (
            <label className="form__group">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleClick} className="form__input" />
                <span className="form__faux-input"></span>
                <span className="form__label">{name}</span>
            </label>
        )
    }
}

function Sidebar({ categories }) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <div className="controls">
                <div className="filter">
                    <h2 className="filter__heading">Filter By Category</h2>
                    <form className="filter-form">
                        {!categories
                            ? <Spinner />
                            : categories.map((item) => (
                                <Checkbox key={item} name={item} />
                            ))
                        }
                        <div className="form__group">
                            <button className="btn btn--rectangle btn--green">
                                <span className="btn-wrapper">Reset</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        books: null,
        categories: null
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { books, categories } = await getBooks();

        this.setState(() => ({
            books: books,
            categories: categories
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { books } = this.state;
        const { categories } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Header />
                <main className="main">
                    <div className="uiContainer">
                        <Sidebar
                            categories={categories}
                        />
                        {!books
                            ? <Spinner />
                            : <Card books={books} />
                        }
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: so what displays the filtered list of books? i think it is supposed to display in the cards component, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

I dont 100% understand the question, but if you want to make a section like

```
[x]  cats
[x]  dogs
[ ]  rabbits // dont show rabbits
```

Then you can keep the selection and the result part in one react element, if you dont understand the 'lifting state up' section

the state should contain an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    allow: true,
    title: 'cat'
},
{allow: false, title: 'rabbit'}]
```

To update the list use something like this:

```
this.state.map(({title, allow}) => (
    <div>
        <TickBox onClick={() => this.toggleAnimal(title)} value={allow}/>
        <p>{animalName}</p>
    </div>
)
```

toggleAnimal function should find the animal using the title, and update the state

Then you can filter out all the not allowed animals

```
this.state
   .filter(animal => animal.allowed)
   .map(a => <p>{a.title}</p>)
```

---

## lifting state up

At this point you have 1 component, and the render function looks like this:

```
<h1>Please select the animals</h1>
{
    animals.map(_ => <div><tickbox onClick={() => this.handleToggle(title)} /><title></div>)
}
<h1>Here are the filtered animals</h1>
{
    animals.filter(a => a.allow).map(animal => animal.title).map(/* to JSX */)
}
```

It would be prettier and more responsive if the root component would look like this:

```
render () {
    <SelectAnimals toggle={handleToggle} animals={this.state} />
    <ShowFilteredAnimals animals={this.state} />
}
handleToggle (title) {
    this.setState(...)
}
```

As so can see, the SelectAnimals gets a function as an argument, it can communicate with it's parent, by calling props.toggle (with the title as argument)

So SelectAnimals would look like this:

```
props.animals.map(animal => (
 <div>
   <TickBox onClick=(() => {props.toggle(animal.title)}) /> // HERE
   <p>{animal.title}</p>
 </div>
))
```

So when the tick-box fires a click event, it calls an arrow func. that calls props.toggle function with the title
In the parent of SelectAnimals, the parent element binds a handler function to SelectAnimals.toggle like this:

```
handleToggle (title) { // the child element called this function, it just got copied
}
```

PS: I made some renames in my code the handleToggle function can be the same as toggleAnimals

Answer (score 0):

The parent component `App` needs to be able to tell `Card` what the selected category is, assuming `Card` is where the list renders.

To do that, you can:

1) create a callback function inside `<App>`:

```
_setCurrentCategory(selection) { 
  this.setState({currentCategory: selection}) 
}
```

2) pass it to `<Checkbox />` as a prop and use it in an `onChange`:

```
  class Checkbox extends Component {
    render() {
        const {name, setCurrentCategoryCallback } = this.props
        return (
            <label className="form__group">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={() => setCurrentCategoryCallback(name)}
                  className="form__input"
                />
                <span className="form__faux-input"></span>
                <span className="form__label">{name}</span>
            </label>
        )
    }
  }
```

.. this will change the state in the parent so that you can then

2) then pass the state from `<App />`  to `<Card />`:

```
<Card 
  currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory} 
  books={books}
/>
```

^^ assuming that this is where the filtered list will render. Inside the Card component, you can filter/order then render the list as you please since it now has both the list of books, and the currently selected category.

This is very loosely coded, but hopefully you get the idea!

also, when deconstructing you don't need to do this:

```
const { books } = this.state;
const { categories } = this.state;
```

you can instead do this: `const { books, categories} = this.state` since they are both coming from state :)